# How to print the actual content of a pdf which matches the search query in solr 7.6.0

Tags: pdf, post, solr, apache-tika

The solr version I am using is 7.6.0 (Schema-less Mode). I have tried to index few PDF documents using the Post utility jar provided by default. Now when I am doing a query, the details of file containing the query string are shown correctly. But I couldn't see any field with actual content of file presented. My Solrconfig.xml's Request Handler is given as follows

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" startup="lazy" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.a">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.div">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">text</str>
      <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <bool name="ignoreTikaException">true</bool>
    </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

When posted the pdf files for indexing, the auto generated managed-schema.xml file didn't contain any "Content" field in it. Also when queried, only the metadata of file like id, date, title, content-types, stream-size, author etc., are shown but not the actual content information highlighted. Please clarify. "http://localhost:8983/solr/TestCore6/select?hl=on&q=mars&wt=json"

Comment: do you share the managed schema file? is the content field has the stored=true in the field definition?

Comment: hl.fl Specifies a list of fields to highlight.

Comment: Thank You Abhijeet! But in my managed-schema.xml file there is no filed only with content generated. Instead there are other fields as given below: 
<field name="access_permission_extract_content" type="booleans"/>
<field name="content_type" type="text_general"/>
<field name="custom_contenttypeid" type="text_general"/>
<field name="stream_content_type" type="text_general"/>

Comment: which is the field you are searching upon?

Comment: CarsH.pdf:
Hyundai Group is a South Korean business conglomerate headquartered in Seoul.Honda Motor is Japanese public multinational conglomerate corporation 
CarsS.pdf:
SWIFT is the world’s leading provider of secure financial messaging services. Discover how we pursue operational excellence. Problem:
Both my pdf fields are indexed. Now from Admin Console when i try to provide query "q" as "Hyundai" the metadata of correct file CarsH.pdf is retrieved with details like filename, author, title etc., but not the original content with few lines of that paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that helped to fix my issue:

The "*text*" field in schema comes with stored="false" by default. This field has to be made true for displaying the content information.

Reference Link: *[Solr query in a pdf file, is not returning highlighting content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43917700/solr-query-in-a-pdf-file-is-not-returning-highlighting-content)*

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to perform a search and if its the highlighting issue then there are other parameters which can be considered for highlighting.

`hl.fl`  Specifies a list of fields to highlight. Accepts a comma- or space-delimited list of fields for which Solr should generate highlighted snippets.

`hl.fragsize`  Specifies the approximate size, in characters, of fragments to consider for highlighting. 0 indicates that no fragmenting should be considered and the whole field value should be used. default is 100.

Below is the link which has list of all the parameters. You need to check which one are applicable and works in your case.

[Highlighting in solr](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/highlighting.html)

Comment: Thanks for the details Abhijeet! I have gone through the highlighting concept and little confused. Without any Content related fields retrieved during search querying will highlighting help? Because when I have done a search "querystring" on the document indexed, it hasn't shown the actual content. It only displayed document metadata fields. But my problem is that it should display a paragraph that matches the query string just like google does. Please clarify if I am in a wrong direction. Thank You !